# Lotus Domino data as JSON

Tags: json, encode, lotus-domino, quoted-printable

My object is to be able to get the data from a notesdocument as JSON
This I can do by using the Domino Data Service via the URL.
The rich text fields are translated to HTML but gets contentTransferEncoding: "quoted-printable"
Is there any way I can avoid that?
Alternatively - another method with which I can get json from all the types of fields in a document - using XPages or java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me that some type of content-transfer-encoding could be  necessary to preserve the integrity of the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [DomJson by Michael Nielsen](http://www.openntf.org/p/DomJson) can help you. It is similar in functionality as Domino Data Service but might offer what you need with regards to rich text fields. If not, then you can extend it to your needs since it's open source :-)

Comment: Yes - I think it would be possible to extend DomJson, because it doesn't include RT fields.

Comment: Probably not an easy task. I consider using ?Openfield feature as it is the only HTML I have seen so far that has no data loss etc.

Comment: My solution will be to let Domino parse the rich text field to HTML and read the HTML page with java. The resulting HTML array will then be encoded to be included in JSON. Not elegant - but it works - inspiration: http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256DC80053681B